# What are the ways to find the exact difference between two strings in Java or Kotlin?

Tags: java, android, string, kotlin

I would like to compare to strings and print the difference. I would also like to print the percentage of similarity between the two strings. I am looking for a solution in Java or Kotlin. Any leads will be really appreciated.

Here is the example for the question.

1. Let's say first string is "Java is very easy"
2. Second string is "Jav is ver easie"

Now, I want to find programmatically that the letter a is missing in "Java" and easy is different. I would like to visually let the reader know the letters where they made the mistake.

I am basically looking for this for an android application. Any leads will be really appreciated.

Comment: Good answers to this can actually be very hard. Especially if you want to be able to do things like find a minor difference (a missing word for example) but recognize the rest of the string is the same.  I would look into diffing algorithms used in things like git, the diff utility, and other similar open source projects and see if there's something you can use.

Comment: It's what the [diff utility](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diff) does. The algorithm (explained on the referenced Wiki page) is the topic of several research papers and computer science curricula. It's not trivial. You can easily find several open-source Kotlin implementations.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to discover the precise differences between the characters of two strings, you can modify 'str1' and 'str2' in the following code with your own strings.

```
 public static void compareChar() {
        String str1 = "i hate java so match";
        String str2 = "i hate java so match";
        char[] charStr1 = str1.toCharArray();
        char[] charStr2 = str2.toCharArray();
        System.out.println("position        str1        str2");


        if (charStr1.length > charStr2.length) {

            for (int i = 0; i < charStr2.length; i++) {
                if (charStr1[i] != charStr2[i]) {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Different");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Not Different");
                }
            }
            for (int i = charStr2.length; i < charStr1.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "         " + "       Different");
            }

        } else if (charStr1.length < charStr2.length) {
            for (int i = 0; i < charStr1.length; i++) {
                if (charStr1[i] != charStr2[i]) {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Different");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Not Different");
                }
            }
            for (int i = charStr1.length; i < charStr2.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr2[i] + "         " + "       Different");
            }

        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < charStr1.length; i++) {
                if (charStr1[i] != charStr2[i]) {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Different");
                } else {
                    System.out.println(i + "       " + charStr1[i] + "        " + charStr1[i] + "      Not Different");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This if effective for strings that are nearly identical and are  transposes (replacing one letter with another), but it's not very effective for missing letters, added letters, or multi letter mistakes.  It also won't work at all on a word level (entire missing words, but returns to similarity afterwards). After it finds the first mistake, every letter after will flag as a mistake as well if it was a missing or added letter.   Your answer isn't wrong, but it's the very simplest version of the algorithm to the point of being mostly unusable in practice.